# grep to compare files not working

Tags: grep

I successfully used:

```
grep -wFf inputqueries.txt seachedfile.txt > results.txt
```

to search searchedfile.txt for each query in inputqueries.txt.

inputqueries.txt looks like:

```
213.183.56.186
216.176.100.240
216.215.112.149
217.23.49.178
222.29.197.232
23.235.201.32
23.253.150.120
202.112.166.5
```

searchedfile.txt looks like

```
168.68.129.127  184.73.191.34
199.133.78.171  202.112.166.5
64.180.139.190  199.141.121.11
199.133.186.162 128.118.250.5
54.145.167.92   168.68.129.73
199.154.229.66  23.75.15.164
162.79.16.103   199.134.135.69
```

and results.txt was correctly

```
199.133.78.171  202.112.166.5
```

**Unfortunately**, that is where my success stopped.  When I put it to work in the real world, it didn't work.  Every time it returned zero results.

I used the same inputqueries.txt as well as one with a query list of words (as opposed to IPs).  Further, it's important to note that I do not have write privileges to the actual log file directories and most of the logs are zipped as *.gz.  Additionally, I'm trying to search multiple similar files at the same time (zcat http*, zcat conn.*, etc)

```
zcat filestosearch.* | grep -wFf /home/username/inputqueries.txt > /home/username/results.txt
```

Didn't work (nor did it work if I took off -wF and left it just grep -f)

```
zgrep -wFf /home/username/inputqueries.txt filestosearch.* > /home/username/results.txt
```

Didn't work either.

The logs I'm searching in real life vary, but the http one looks like... (they are all bro logs)

```
1432343999.435553       CuCcn04H20cc2ZHyEh      202.170.48.4    50501   197.138.26.55   80      4       GET     ndb.nal.usda.gov        /ndb/search/autosuggest?manu=&amp;fgcd=&term=Coconut+milk       http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods?fgcd=&manu=&lfacet=&count=&max=35&sort=&qlookup=Oil%2C+palm&offset=&format=Abridged&new=&measureby=   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Safari/537.36    0       12994   200     OK      -       -       -       (empty) -       -       -       -       -       FGGh0g4a24L8Q6CZUb     text/plain
1432343999.382108       CKPWGW2cubkRjFpTKf      197.166.19.125   63803   54.191.210.216  80      1       GET     client.ql2.com  /cc/diff/http.www.ars.usda.gov/_22Fpandp_22Flocations_22FcityPeopleList.cfm_23Fmodecode_23D60-64-05-10/20150409123538diff.html  -       WebTrends/3.0 (WinNT)  00       302     Moved Temporarily       -       -       -       (empty) -       -       -       -       -       -       -
1432343999.595036       Cz4XJl3uaq2Fxc0M9a      63.248.145.199  63004   197.155.76.112  80      1       GET     start2farm.gov  /sites/all/themes/contrib/twitter_bootstrap/images/arrow-green.png      http://start2farm.gov/  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko     0       1498    200     OK      -       -       -       (empty) -       -       -       -       -       Fo69Ao3w36RxKcoH9f     image/png
1432343999.732470       CTPQZyQ7tX7BUjU5j       197.123.240.10    56863   216.58.217.132  80      36      GET     toolbarqueries.google.com      /tbr?client=navclient-auto&ch=63738508926&features=Rank&q=info:/url?q=http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK8125/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=FjjmVJriAceagwSM1oOIDg&amp;ved=0CBsQFjAB&amp;usg=AFQjCNHgMKW6EIWKxclKB9o-o21bQu7IOw     -       Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618)    0       5928    403     Forbidden       -      --       (empty) -       -       -       -       -       F2UdRnxrFUEHJFdW4       text/html
```

**Using the simplest single-line command that I can, how do I make the grep from a file work?**

Comment: Are you sure that there are actual matches?  Granted, you only showed a small sample, but I don't think any of those would be matched.  Can you show us one that should be matched, but wasn't?

Comment: @EricRenouf I thought the same thing so I went back and grepped a known keyword based on a quick glance in the http.* and it worked fine.  Further, I then added search queries that were simple words like the and portal to the inputqueries.txt, which should have given me a file at least a GB in size, but still 0 bytes for the results.txt.

Comment: Did you create the input file on Windows?  If there are hidden `\r`  characters at the ends of the lines that could explain it.  You might want to try to `dos2unix` it and see if that helps

Comment: The initial test query file with IPs was created in Windows (Notepad++).  The subsequent query files with IPs and words have been created in both Notepad++ and VIM since I thought that might be an issue.  Still doesn't help.  I think it must be a syntax issue.  Could the tab space in the actual files versus the single space in the successful initial search be the problem?

Comment: So you actively converted using a tool like `dos2unix`?  When I created a quick file and did your same experiment a `\r` caused the effects you're reporting.  Vim wouldn't have automatically converted the file for you.

Comment: @EricRenouf  No, I don't have that program.  However, vim was used to create a new file from scratch when I was trying to get this to work, so would the \r still be an issue?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't think if the file has only been on *nix that it would, but since it's the only theory I have, try running this GNU sed script to strip any whitespace from the ends of lines: `sed -i -e 's/\s*$//' inputqueries.txt`  If you don't have GNU sed `-i` won't work like.

Comment: @EricRenouf  Please add that information as an answer on this thread so I can give you credit.  I must have mixed up the test files at some point and polluted the content, because your sed cleaner works flawlessly.  Everything works perfectly now.  If you wouldn't mind explaining how that sed command works, I would appreciate learning more why it works so well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the file(s) were edited on Windows at some point, which added some extra `\r` characters to the ends, which aren't normally visible.

If you have the `dos2unix` command you can use that to convert the file.  If you don't have that and there isn't any important whitespace at the ends of lines you can do it with GNU sed as follows:

```
sed -i -e 's/\s*$//' inputqueries.txt
```

to modify the file in place (the `-i` flag) and then replace any amount of whitespace at the end of the line with nothing, effectively deleting it.  `-i` is not part of POSIX though, so if you need a portable solution you can use the rest of the `sed` command and redirect to a temporary file.  When you're sure that file is right, rename it to the file you actually want.